# MAC address unreachable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I cannot reach five wireless repeaters mounted several feet in the air to read the MAC addresses.  Is there any other way to access the MAC address for each node?

Comment: The MAC address is usually accessible via the web interface.

Comment: do you know the IP addresses of the machines? you could ARP them to discover their mac's.

Comment: How are the repeaters configured? If they connect as stations, just look at the MAC address for any traffic that originates from one of their clients.

Answer (score 1):

If the wireless repeaters are up and running, a packet sniffer tool or even a Wi-Fi network scanner like inSSIDer should be able to see their MAC addresses in the beacons they're transmitting.

Note that this only gets their MAC addresses for their wireless interfaces (BSSIDs), not their wired Ethernet MAC addresses (if any, if that's what you care about).